Uso de API POST VTEX en Jmeter
Me podrian ayudar con una duda para correr una API de VTEX por Jmeter.
Debo cargar un .csv con aprox 400.000 imágenes alojadas en un ftp, postman claramente no soportaría tal volumen de carga, por tanto estoy optando por Jmeter.
Me podrían indicar que estoy haciendo mal, gracias:

Thread Group

CSV Data Set Config

HTTP Request/body data

HTTP Request/Files Upload

HTTP Header Manager


La API que se esta usando es esta: https://developers.vtex.com/docs/api-reference/catalog-api#post-/api/catalog/pvt/stockkeepingunit/-skuId-/file?endpoint=post-/api/catalog/pvt/stockkeepingunit/-skuId-/file
Gracias de antemano

Mal está que pongas la información fuera de este sitio. Edita la pregunta y pon en ella toda la información relevante.
